# Why the null space of pseudo inverse equals the null space of the matrix transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

The pseudoinverse $A^+$ of A is the matrix for which $x = A^+Ax$ for all x in the row space of A. The nullspace of $A^+$ is the nullspace of $A^T$.

I don't understand this cause the above seems to imply that $A^+=A^T$ which doesn't make sense as $x = A^+Ax$ while $A^TA$ gives a matrix which is not an identity matrix.

Here is the [source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/left-and-right-inverses-pseudoinverse/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses3.8sum.pdf)-Page 2 on "Finding the pseudo Inverse"

Comment: Use the SVD of $A$ to express the pseudoinverse of $A$. The relationship should then become clear.

Comment: I will get $A^+=VΣ^+U^T$ where matrix $Σ^+$ whose first r rows have $\frac{1}{σ_1}, \frac{1}{σ_2}, ..., \frac{1}{σ_r}$ on the diagonal. But I feel to see why or the intuition behind how that will equate to the transpose.

Comment: Well $A^T = V\Sigma^TU^T$. They both have the same nullspace, namely, $U_{r+1:m}$, where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: So the Σ doesn't matter but it is because both consists of the matrix multiplication between V and $U^T$ right? The Σ is more like the scalar product between the two right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Define matrix

Start with a matrix 
$$
 \mathbf{A} \in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}
$$

### Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra

The Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra can be expressed as
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$

### Singular value decomposition

The singular value decomposition of the matrix is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\\hline
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
  & =
% U
   \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{n}}
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
    \vdots \\
    \color{blue}{v_{\rho}^{*}} \\
    \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}^{*}} \\
    \vdots \\ 
    \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The connection to the Fundamental Theorem is intimate:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
%
     column \ vectors & span \\\hline
%
     \color{blue}{u_{1}}  \dots  \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & 
     \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
     \color{blue}{v_{1}}  \dots  \color{blue}{v_{\rho}} & 
     \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \\
%
     \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}}  \dots  \color{red}{u_{m}} & 
     \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \\
%
     \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}}  \dots  \color{red}{v_{n}} & 
     \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \end{array}
$$

### Pseudoinverse matrix

The least squares solution with the SVD produces the pseudoinverse:

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{+} &= \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{+} \mathbf{U}^{*} \\
%
&=
% V
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right] 
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
%
% U
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
\end{align}
%
$$
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{+} \in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}_{\rho}
$$

The subspace decomposition in terms of the pseudoinverse is now explicit.

### Adjoint matrix

For comparison, the adjoint matrix is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{*} &= \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{T} \mathbf{U}^{*} \\
%
&=
% V
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right] 
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
%
% U
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
\end{align}
$$
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{*} \in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}_{\rho}
$$

---

**Further reading**

How the pseudoinverse solution arises in least squares: [How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/how-does-the-svd-solve-the-least-squares-problem); [Singular value decomposition proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209379/singular-value-decomposition-proof/2211001#2211001)

Variant forms of the pseudoinverse are presented in [What forms does the Moore-Penrose inverse take under systems with full rank, full column rank, and full row rank?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537880/what-forms-does-the-moore-penrose-inverse-take-under-systems-with-full-rank-ful/2200203#2200203); [generalized inverse of a matrix and convergence for singular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241296/generalized-inverse-of-a-matrix-and-convergence-for-singular-matrix/2242261#2242261) Note the null space relationships with the pseudoinverse.

Fundamental projectors and the pseudoinverse: [Least squares solutions and the orthogonal projector onto the column space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033896/least-squares-solutions-and-the-orthogonal-projector-onto-the-column-space/2180194#2180194)

Comment: What does "⊕" indicate? And what exactly is $V_R$ vs $V_N$?

Comment: The symbol ⊕ represents a [direct sum] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Examples) between range space elements and null space elements, spaces that only share the point at the origin. The row space $\mathbf{V}$ resolves into range space $\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}$ and null space $\color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}$ components.