# Existence of left or right pseudoinverse

Tags: matrix-rank, pseudoinverse

I'm a bit confused about the following question:

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}$, which one of the left or right pseudoinverse does exist?

I know that the left pseudoinverse exists, if $A$ has full column rank and the right pseudoinverse exists, if $A$ has full row rank.
I know further that a rank is full, iff **rank**$(A) = \min(2, 3) = 2$ is.
But do I not need an explicit matrix to determine the rank of the matrix resp. the fullness of the rank?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a matrix $A$ maps $\mathbb R^3$ into $\mathbb R^2$, so it cannot be an injective map. Thus, $A$ cannot have a left pseudoinverse.

Comment: Sorry, two issues:
1. I get the intuition why the mapping from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be injective (consider a projection on a plane etc.). But I have no idea how the formal proof of this looks like, because we have two infinite sets, so there could possibly be an unique element in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for each element in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

2. I don't understand the step from the non-injectivity to the non existence of the left pseudoinverse.

Comment: If you're mapping a vector space of dimension $n$ into a vector space of dimension $m$ with $n>m$, then this map cannot be injective (this can be proven from the rank-nullity theorem for instance since we can show that the nullity is positive). Then one can use the characterisation that a map is injective if and only if it has a left inverse.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I think, I got the right proof now. Then the right pseudoinverse does exist? Is it necessary/possible to show that?

Comment: A right inverse won't always exist, e.g. consider the zero matrix. But it is possible that for some $A$ a right inverse will exist.

Answer (score 3):

Details in [What forms does the Moore-Penrose inverse take under systems with full rank, full column rank, and full row rank?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537880/what-forms-does-the-moore-penrose-inverse-take-under-systems-with-full-rank-ful/2200203#2200203).

## Summary

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$ where $\rho\ge 1$, the singular value decomposition exists, and can be used to construct the pseudoinverse matrix $\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}$.

[image: table of cases]

### Block decomposition: general case

The block decompositions for the target matrix and the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse are
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &= \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
= 
% U 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}^{*})}} 
 \end{array} \right] 
% Sigma 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
\mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\ 
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
 \end{array} \right] 
% V 
\left[ \begin{array}{l}
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}^{*})}^{*}} \\
  \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})}^{*}}
\end{array} \right]
\\
%%
  \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} &= \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{\dagger} \, \mathbf{U}^{*}
= 
% U 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}^{*})}} & 
 \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})}} 
 \end{array} \right] 
% Sigma 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
\mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\ 
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
 \end{array} \right] 
% V 
\left[ \begin{array}{l}
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})}^{*}} \\
  \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}^{*})}^{*}}
\end{array} \right]
\end{align}
$$
Blue entities live in range spaces, red in null spaces.

Sort the least squares solutions into special cases according to the null space structures.

[image: block forms]

### Special cases

#### Square: Both null spaces are trivial: full row rank, full column rank

$$ m = n = \rho: \qquad \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}$$
Block structures:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\mathbf{A} &= 
&\color{blue}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{R}}}} 
&\mathbf{S}
&\color{blue}{\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{R}}^{*}}} \\
\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} &= 
&\color{blue}{\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{R}}}} 
&\mathbf{S}^{-1}
&\color{blue}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{R}}^{*}}}
\end{array}
$$

Verify the classic inverse:
$$\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{I}_{n}$$

#### Tall: Only $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}_{\mathbf{A}}}$ is non trivial: full column rank

$$ m > n,  n = \rho: \qquad \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{A}^{-L}$$
Block structures:
$$
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{A} & = 
%
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
   \color{blue}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{R}}^{*}}} &
   \color{red}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{N}}}}
\end{array} \right] 
%
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \mathbf{S} \\ 
    \mathbf{0}
  \end{array} \right]
%
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{R}}}} 
\\
% Apinv
 \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} & = 
%
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{R}}}} \, 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
    \mathbf{S}^{-1} & 
    \mathbf{0}
  \end{array} \right]
%
 \left[ \begin{array}{c}
   \color{blue}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{R}}^{*}}} \\
   \color{red}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{N}}^{*}}}
\end{array} \right]
\end{align}
$$

Verify the left inverse:
$$\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}^{-L}\mathbf{A} =  \left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}_{m}$$

#### Wide: Only $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}_{\mathbf{A}^{*}}}$ is non trivial: full row rank

$$ m < n,  m = \rho: \qquad \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{A}^{-L}$$
Block structures:
$$
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{A} & = 
%
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{R}}}}
\, 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
    \mathbf{S} &
    \mathbf{0}
  \end{array} \right]
%
 \left[ \begin{array}{c}
   \color{blue}{\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{R}}^{*}}} \\
   \color{red} {\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{N}}^{*}}}
\end{array} \right]
%
 \\
% Apinv
 \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} & = 
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
   \color{blue}{\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{R}}}} &
   \color{red} {\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{N}}}}
\end{array} \right]
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \mathbf{S}^{-1} \\
    \mathbf{0}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{R}}^{*}}}
%
\end{align}
$$

Verify the right inverse:
$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = 
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{-R} =  
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{*} \left( \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)^{-1} = \mathbf{I}_{n}$$